# add onclick function for submit button

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to add an `onclick` function to an `<input type="submit">`? I would like to show a hidden `<div>` named "div2" when the submit button is clicked inside a form.

Comment: You should be aware that once the `Submit` button has been clicked, the browser will start loading a new page.. Any changes you make to the current page will be lost. Can you explain to us WHY you want to show a hidden `<div>` for the brief moments before the new page has loaded?

Comment: @jnpcl - onclick of submit button the browser will not load another page because i didn't add a action="" on the form declaration. i want to show a hidden div because the value to be submitted by the submit button will be thrown to the shown div.

Comment: Why use `submit` then? why not just `button`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that you need to stop the default behavior of clicking the submit button or else the form will be submitted and a new page will load before the `div` ever get's displayed. For example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showDiv() {
            document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
            return false;
        }
    </script>

    <div id="div2" style="display: none;">Visible</div>
    <form name="test_form" action="#">
         <input type="submit" onclick="return showDiv();" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Using this code the form will now not submit and the `div` will be shown. If you then want to submit the form later you need to either change `showDiv()` to return `true`, use another submit button or call the `submit()` method of the form.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked() {
        alert('clicked');
    }
</script>

<input type="submit" onclick="clicked();" value="Button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
   return false; // this stops further executing of the script so the form will not be submitted
}
```

if you're not using the button for submitting the form I can suggest you to use:

```
<input type="button" id="showDiv" value="show div" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on it a little while. I found a very easy way! Here it is:

```
<?php
function test()
{
print "HI!" ;
}
?>

<form action="index.html" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Reset" name="reset" >
<?php
if ($_POST["reset"]= Reset) test() ?>
</form>
```

in this code index.html is the same file as in the code. (link to the same file or "reload")
Reset is the reset button for a function.
so in the end if you dont click the button, i'll be this:

```
if ( = Reset) test()
```

this is not true so it wont execute the function test()

if you press the button it will send you to the same site giving the $_post a function

if you press the button you will get this:

```
if ( Reset = Reset ) test()
```

this is true. and will print HI!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your hidden DIV (named "div2") is hidden because its style.display was set to 'none':

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('div2').style.display = '';">
```

Comment: In order to stop the form from being submitted you need to write in the `<form action="..." method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">` and you need to manually perform the submission via JS by using `form.submit();`