# add onclick function to a submit button

Tags: onclick, submit

I'm just learning javascript and php.  I created a contact form and I'd like the submit button to accomplish two things when I press it:

1. submit the data to me (this part is working)
2. read my onclick function (this part is not working)

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="eatFood()">

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
 ////????? 
}
?>
```

I'm sending the data to my email, and so I get that.  But the `onclick` function doesn't seem to work.  I tried reviewing [add onclick function for submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356011/add-onclick-function-for-submit-button) but it didn't help.

Comment: show us your code, to evaluate whats wrong

Comment: You don't *have* an `eatFood` function in that code.

Comment: ```document.forms['formID'].reportValidity()``` returns true if all the form elements validity is true.

Answer (score 94):

I need to see your submit button html tag for better help. I am not familiar with php and how it handles the postback, but I guess depending on what you want to do, you have three options:

1. Getting the handling `onclick` button on the client-side: In this case you only need to call a javascript function.

```js
function foo() {
   alert("Submit button clicked!");
   return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return foo();" />
```

2. If you want to handle the click on the server-side, you should first make sure that the form tag method attribute is set to `post`:

   ```
   <form method="post">
   ```
3. You can use `onsubmit` event from `form` itself to bind your function to it.

```html
<form name="frm1" method="post" onsubmit="return greeting()">
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: onsubmit of the form is the better handler. If you do not have a form, change to `type="button"`

Comment: @mplungjan tanx for the tip, I added that to the answer

Comment: No +1 yet due to poor choice in reference material ;)

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't realize the link wasn't in anchor. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 29):

html:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">    
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="eatFood();" />
</form>
```

Javascript:
to submit the form using javascript

```
function eatFood() {
document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
```

to show onclick message

```
function eatFood() {
alert('Form has been submitted');
}
```

Answer (score 20):

if you need to do something before submitting data, you could use form's **onsubmit**.

```
<form method=post onsubmit="return doSomething()">
  <input type=text name=text1>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have this code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
function deshabilitarBoton() {     
    document.getElementById("boton").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("envio").innerHTML ="<br><img src='img/loading.gif' width='16' height='16' border='0'>Generando...";     
    return true;
} 
</SCRIPT>
<title>untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" action="ok.do" method="post" >
<table>
<tr>
<td>Fecha inicio:</td>
<td><input type="TEXT" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio"  /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="boton">
   <input type="submit" name="event" value="Enviar" class="button" onclick="return deshabilitarBoton()" />
</div>
<div id="envio">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a hidden button with `id="hiddenBtn"` and `type="submit"` that do the submit
2. Change current button to `type="button"`
3. set `onclick` of the current button call a `function` look like below:

```
function foo() {
    // do something before submit
    ...
    // trigger click event of the hidden button
    $('#hinddenBtn').trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" name="uname" value="uname" onclick="browserlink(ex.google.com,home.html etc)or myfunction();"> submit</button>
```

if you want  to open a page on the click of a  button in HTML without any scripting language then you can use above code.

Comment: How does `onclick` returns `myfunction()`, but force the browser to stay on the same page. The function will just say "Thank you for your feedback."  My form is connected to a local php file(`formsubmit.php`):  `<form action="formsubmit.php" id="contact-form" target="_blank" method="post"
          enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">`