# MVC4 Call back from server to client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 application, I need to Display messages in the Client, by sending messages from Controller to Client.

I need to Upload a file to Server and Do Some Processing in the Foreach loop and Once each foreach i need to display message in the UI.
Currently i have for Loop I need to Send message from Server to Client on each for loop in this case

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formUpload", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        <b>Upload File</b>
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="btnUpload" onclick="progressStatus();"/><br />
    </div>
    <div>
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div id="progressbar" style="width: 300px; height: 15px"></div>
        <br />
    </div>
}
```

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        var fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var exis = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Storage/uploads"), fname);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(exis))
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "The file " + fname + " has already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Storage/uploads");
                    fname = fileName;
                    var path = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);
                    var filebytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        //Display This Message in UI From here each time for runs like i want to show user message 1,2,3,4 etc each time for runs
                    }
                }
                ViewData["Message"] = "The file " + fname + " has uploaded successully";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "The file " + fname + " Could not upload";
                ViewData["Message"] = e.Message;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        ViewData["Message"] = "Please choose file";
                return View();
}
```

Comment: Initialize a `List<string>` and ad you messages to it, then assign it to a `ViewBag` (or preferably a view model) property so that you can iterate over then in the view.

Comment: If you are looking at `on the fly` progress messages to the client browser, then you got to use something like `SignalR`. With traditional ASP.Net MVC api, you cannot push notifications to client browser.

Comment: I am New to MVC 4 Can you help me how to do this, Like a HTTP Response message

Comment: I would suggest looping that using ajax and do the operations corresponding to that loop in server and meanwhile you can show the message to clent

Comment: Vivekh Can you please tell me how to Do that

Comment: Issue is here - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxsmOUXQZiJHaFF4MDFvaG5PcVU&authuser=0

Comment: @BharatReddy This is a perfect situation for using [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).  As it's quite a large subject, a full solution doesn't really fit with the SO question-answer format.  You can find plenty of full examples on how to do this, eg on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary key value pair in each iteration of loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    ViewData["Message_"+i.ToString()] = //your message;
                }
```

Comment: I need to Return to View Each time the For each runs how to achieve that

Comment: Thats some strange requirement, why cant u put for loop in view as well and access using index.

Comment: I am New to MVC so -> My requirement is Once i saved a file in some Location i need to Process the file like in the for loop in that i might run the for loop may be 10 times or 20 times based on some parameters and i want to return message each for loop to UI

Comment: @BharatReddy, You cant return the view in each iteration. As soon as you return the view you exit the method!

Comment: my code -https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxsmOUXQZiJHaFF4MDFvaG5PcVU&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use `StringBuilder`:

    var sb = new StringBuilder();      

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
         bool isValid = doSomeThing();

         if (isValid)
         {
            sb.Append("<li>Loop success : " + i + "</li>");     
         }
         else
         {
            sb.Append("<li>Error in loop : " + i + "</li>");         
          }

      }

    viewBag.msg = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I need to Push Messages from Client to server how to do that .. Like a Progress File Processing and a message