# Asp.NET MVC 4 Ajax Request Cancels on Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

Issue Is with Ajax Request Cancel
After i call the ProcessMessage from form submit i am having issue

Issue with submitting your page is canceling my ajax request, so I am getting error..
Please help me on this

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formUpload", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        <b>Upload File</b>

        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="btnUpload" onclick="progressStatus();"/><br />

    </div>

    <div>
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>

    <div style="width: 30%; margin: 0 auto;">

        <div id="progressbar" style="width: 300px; height: 15px"></div>
        <br/>
    </div>

}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">
    function progressStatus() {

        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.open("get", "/Home/ProcessMessage", true);
        oReq.send();
        setInterval(showResult, 1000);

        function showResult() {
            var result = "";
            if (result !== oReq.responseText) {
                result = oReq.responseText;
                debugger;
                $("#progressbar").html(result);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    var fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    var exis = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Storage/uploads"), fname);
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(exis))
                    {
                        ViewData["Message"] = "The file " + fname + " has already exists";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       try
                       {
                            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                                var folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Storage/uploads");
                                fname = fileName;
                                var path = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

                                var filebytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];

                                if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

                                file.SaveAs(path);

                            }
                            ViewData["Message"] = "The file " + fname + " has uploaded successully";
                       }
                       catch (Exception e)
                       {
                            ViewData["Message"] = "The file " + fname + " Could not upload";
                          ViewData["Message"] = e.Message;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    ViewData["Message"] = "Please choose file";
                    return View();
            }

public class ProgressiveResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write(i.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        }
        context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
and this is an action that returns this result:

public ActionResult ProcessMessage()
{
   return new ProgressiveResult();
}
```

Comment: What the error is exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return false in click event handler to cancel submitting the form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="btnUpload" onclick="progressStatus(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: You have to put code of Index in the action method that your ajax calls. As you may guess, You have to put your file processing code in the ProgressiveActionResult.ExecuteResult and return your progress status there.