# ajax form request still reloads page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, jquery-mobile

I am trying to submit a form using ajax with jquery mobile without it refreshing the page and am having no luck..

I have this form -

index.php:

```
<script>
function SubmitForm() {
var name = $("#name").val();
$.post("bump.php", { name: name},
function(data) {
 //alert(data);
});
}
</script>


<form method="post" data-ajax="false">
<input name="name" type="hidden" id="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="image" style="height:35px;top:4px;" id="bump" src="../img/bump.png" id="searchForm" onclick="SubmitForm();" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Here is bump.php

```
$date = date('y/m/d H:i:s');
$id =  $_POST['name'];
$sql = "UPDATE images SET update_date='$date' WHERE id=$id";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
```

I would like to maintain my position on the page but it refreshes each time? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you can use this link might be helpful for you
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944329/add-onclick-function-to-a-submit-button)

Comment: might be helpful for you
[add onclick function to a submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944329/add-onclick-function-to-a-submit-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`event.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) *Cancels the event if it is cancelable, without stopping further propagation of the event.*

Default behaviour of `type="image"` is to submit the `form` hence page is `unloaded`

```js
function SubmitForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  $.post("bump.php", {
      name: name
    },
    function(data) {
      //alert(data);
    });
}
```

```html
<form method="post" data-ajax="false">
  <input name="name" type="hidden" id="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
  <input type="image" style="height:35px;top:4px;" id="bump" src="../img/bump.png" id="searchForm" onclick="SubmitForm(event);" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ahh perfect thanks! @Rayon have to wait 8 min, to accept

Comment: Haa go figure.. Heres a follow up for extra points, when the form submits the hidden field, it has the correct id inserted but when I echo the id in bump.php its the id from the most recent id in the db not the id that was inserted in the hidden field.. Very strange..  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

user return false in onclick`

```js
function SubmitForm() {
//event.preventDefault();
var name = $("#name").val();
console.log(name);
$.post("message.html", { name: name},
function(data) {
 alert(data);
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" data-ajax="false">
<input name="name" type="hidden" id="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="image" style="height:35px;top:4px;" id="bump" src="http://switchon.global2.vic.edu.au/files/2015/07/4x5-1jroh2i.png" id="searchForm" onclick="SubmitForm(); return false;" value="Send" />
</form>
```