# Submit Button not working - could be broken code?

Tags: html, forms, widget

Need help to get my `form` working. I am creating it for a website as a small school project.

Below is the code to the submit button. Am I missing something? (I can place the whole code if needed):

```
<form>
    <!-- END_ITEMS -->
    <input type="hidden" name="EParam" value="FzpUCZwnDno=" />
    <div class="outside_container">
        <input type="button" onclick="Vromansys.FormBuilder.showPreview()" value="Submit Form" class="submit_button" id="FSsubmit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: </div>
<form>
<!-- END_ITEMS -->
<input type="hidden" name="EParam" value="FzpUCZwnDno=" />
<div class="outside_container">
<input type="button" onclick="Vromansys.FormBuilder.showPreview()" value="Submit Form" class="submit_button" id="FSsubmit"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Just remove <form> tag and try to execute code

Comment: That didn't work. I had placed the <form> tag while testing -- took it out but still doesnt work. So i want when the submit button is clicked, the form infor or data should go to an email. where do i add that?

Comment: Anyone else out there willing to help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try input type="submit" ... instead of "button"? It should work with "submit" when using "form".

Best regards,

Dino

Comment: That did not work either.  I think the error might be with "Vromansys.FormBuilder.showPreview()"  -  I am not sure if i need to replace this something else. Also, i would like to have the form sent to an email..is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that it is a cause of error. I can't tell for sure so i can only point you in few directions and is up to you to try and see. If you want to send form data to other page, you can use action attribute in form tag. If you want to intercept submit then do something else in javascript you can find answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944329/add-onclick-function-to-a-submit-button