# onclick with a function does not run function on button click

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to run a function when I click the submit button on my form without the php submitting it.

I tried using `onclick="return func_name();"` & `onClick="return func_name();"` but that hasnt worked for me. Also tried changing the input type of the button from `submit` to `button` but even that hasnt worked. The php `else` inside the `if` condition runs regardless of the function having a `return false` inside the function.

php for the submit-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($username!='')
            {
                $sql_add="INSERT into work_transaction(work_date,from_time,to_time,work_total_hours,project_name,work_module,task,wprk_description,emp_name,add_date,assigned_by,ticket_no,title, is_billable) values ('$regdate','$fromtime','$totime','$tothr','$OTHP','$module','$_POST[title]','$_POST[worksdetail]','$username','$adddate','$_POST[assignText]','$_POST[ticket_no]','$_POST[title]', '$_POST[is_billable]')"; 
                //echo $sql_add;exit();
                $query_add=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql_add) or die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]));
                if(!$query_add)
                {           
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Your Task Details have not been added");
                    </script>
                    <?php
                }
                else{
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Your Task Details has been added successfully");
                        var r = "Your Competitor Details has been added successfully";
                        window.location="add_working_details.php";
                    </script>
                <?php
                }
            }
    }
else{}
```

the function -

```
function submit(){
    alert("dont submit");
    return false;
}
```

The submit button -

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="return submit();">
```

the expected output should be the alert show the message but its not, not sure what im doing wrong.
thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add onclick function to a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944329/add-onclick-function-to-a-submit-button)

Comment: You don't need the return keyword in the onclick parameter.

Comment: @Dharman That is not the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

use preventDefault like below code. preventDefault will prevent all default events then you can run on your code

```js
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('preventing')
});
```

```html
<button id="mybutton">Submit</button>
```