# Is there a way to detect if a user has not answered an input?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a name picker and I want to detect if your user has input a name or if they are just messing with the website. Is there a way to do this?
Code:

```html
<html>
<textarea id="names"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Pick" onclick="onClick(this)">
<p id="chosen"></p>
</html>
<script>
function onClick(x) {
//Your code
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `getNames()` method is called for the `<input>` element to check for value when it submits, and a value is returned after the value inside the `<textarea>` element is checked.

```js
/* This helper method checks whether the login has been made or not. */
function isNameEmpty(){
   var name = document.getElementById("names");
   
   if(name.value.length != 0){
      console.log(name.value);
      return false;
   }
   else{
      console.log('No value was entered.');
      return true;
   }
}

/* This submit method is used to return the entered name. */
function getNames(){
  if(!isNameEmpty()){
    return document.getElementById("names").value;
  }
  else{
    alert('No value was entered.');
    return '';
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="names"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Pick" onclick="return getNames();">
<p id="chosen"></p>
```

---

###### References

- [Add onclick function to a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944329/add-onclick-function-to-a-submit-button)

Comment: this is a good option, also you can avoid user doesn't type anything adding the "required" property into your input tag like: <textarea id="names" required></textarea>

Comment: @santrix I edited it to take a more logical form.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the textarea to input tag and you can use browser built in attributes like type= text min max length etc.

otherwise you should write a function that reads and evaluates the input value of the textarea