# click event on jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have printed an echo with php of input element and I need to get click event id using jquery. Below is the code I am trying to get

API.php(echo element to index.php using ajax):

```
echo"<input type='submit' id='something' value='accept me'/>";
```

index.php(need to get the id='something' in click event):

```
$("#something").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    //doesnt work 
});
```

why it is not working? Please suggest

Comment: have you wrapped it inside $( document ).ready(function() function ?

Comment: I'd imagine its bcoz your binding to #something before it exists in the DOM. Try `$('input').on('click', '#something', function(){ // whatever });

Comment: are you sure you write click event after input html, and you write javascript referance to jquery file location

Comment: And yes, wrap it in document.ready as @thepiyush said and read about event delegation

Comment: @Doron: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `onclick()` function on `input` itself. It will work.

For more info, click [Add Onclick On Submit Button - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356011/add-onclick-function-for-submit-button)

```
<form ... >
    .
    .
    <input type='submit' id='something' onclick="return showValue();" value='accept me'/>
</form>

<script>
function showValue() {
    alert('hi');
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Seems the OP doesn't know how things go on Stack. [I left them this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103171/click-event-on-jquery-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment68057670_34103171) but seems to be to no avail. Oh well, what can you do.

Answer (score 1):

```
 window.onload=function(){
         $("#something").click(function(){
           alert("hi");
         });
      }
```

Comment: forgot to mention   $(function(){$("#something").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    //doesnt work 
});}); still doesnt work

Comment: <html>
<head>
    <title>Rate if it helps</title>
    <!-- PUT A PATH OF JQUERY LIBRARY -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            $("#something").click(function () {
                alert("hi");
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='submit' id='something' value='accept me' />
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#something").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    //doesnt work 
});
});
```

if that does not work then you need to show your code.  http://jsfiddle.net/y6bgov3e/

Answer (score 0):

Here is running code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type='button' id='test' value='accept me'/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').bind('click', function(){
        alert('Hello')
    })
})
</script>
```

If you want to click on button then use button type insted of submit